# Change FontSize of Labeled in TimelinePlot

Tags: plotting

I want to create a timeline using `TimelinePlot`. Above every element I want to write some text/label. Right now I am using `Labeled` for that. Which results in the following plot:

[image: example timeline plot]

```
data1 = {0, 2.68*60, 3.32*60, 07.18*60};
data2 = {3.48*60, 3.48*60, 4.23*60};
test = TimelinePlot[{
   {Labeled[data1[[1]], "text1", Above],
    Labeled[data1[[2]], "text2", Above],
    Labeled[data1[[3]], "text3", Above],
    Labeled[data1[[4]], "text4", Above]},
   {Labeled[data2[[2]], "text5", Above],
    Labeled[data2[[3]], "text6", Above]}
   }
  , PlotLegends -> Placed[{"1", "2"}, Below]
  , Filling -> Axis
  , LabelStyle -> {FontColor -> Black, FontSize -> 16, 
    FontFamily -> "Arial"}
  , PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"
  ]
```

The Plot looks exactly as I want, except for the font size of the labels. How can I change the font size of text1 to text6? `LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 16]` does not work inside `TimelinePlot`. Neither does `Callout` instead of `Labeled`.

Removing `Above`  from `Labeled` makes the labels change to the correct font size, but the whole plot does not look as intended anymore:

[image: example timeline2 plot]

Comment: Since you are going to the double of constructing each Labeled expression, add Style to your text label, eg `Labeled[data[[1]], Style["text1", 16], Above]`. You will probably want to generate the entries programmatically; maybe look at `MapThread`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 16, FontFamily -> "Arial"}`:

```
TimelinePlot[{{Labeled[data1[[1]], "text1", Above], 
   Labeled[data1[[2]], "text2", Above], 
   Labeled[data1[[3]], "text3", Above], 
   Labeled[data1[[4]], "text4", Above]}, 
  {Labeled[data2[[2]], "text5",  Above], 
   Labeled[data2[[3]], "text6", Above]}}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"1", "2"}, Below],
 Filling -> Axis, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 16, FontFamily -> "Arial"}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another way is set `PlotLayout -> "Stacked"` etc.

```
data1 = {0, 2.68*60, 3.32*60, 07.18*60};
data2 = {3.48*60, 3.48*60, 4.23*60};
test = TimelinePlot[{{Labeled[data1[[1]], "text1"], 
    Labeled[data1[[2]], "text2"], Labeled[data1[[3]], "text3"], 
    Labeled[data1[[4]], "text4"]}, {Labeled[data2[[2]], "text5"], 
    Labeled[data2[[3]], "text6"]}}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"1", "2"}, Below], Filling -> Axis, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontColor -> Black, FontSize -> 16, 
    FontFamily -> "Arial"}, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", 
  PlotLayout -> "Stacked"]
```

[image]